# Can't copy sqlite database from assets folder in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to copy a sqlite database file from assets folder so that i create a sqlite database and use it in my program, here is the code:-

first the `SqliteOpenHelperClass`

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
protected static final String DATABASE_NAME_PRODUCTION = "productionComments.db";

public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                     int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

       //copy database from assets folder (.sqlite) file to an empty database
        public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open("prod.db");

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = "/data/data/com.qarun.qpcbeta/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME_PRODUCTION;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
```

Now the activity where i am supposed to call the `copyDatabase()` method:-

```
public class ProductionCommentsActivity extends Activity {
private DBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_production_comments);
    dbHandler = new DBHandler(this, dbHandler.DATABASE_NAME_PRODUCTION, null, 1);
    try {
        dbHandler.copyDataBase();
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("copydb",e.getMessage());
        //Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the error in the logcat:-

```
Process: com.qarun.qpcbeta, PID: 1271
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.qarun.qpcbeta/com.qarun.qpcbeta.ProductionCommentsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
        at com.qarun.qpcbeta.DBHandler.copyDataBase(DBHandler.java:100)
        at com.qarun.qpcbeta.ProductionCommentsActivity.onCreate(ProductionCommentsActivity.java:24)


   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The app stops working (crashes) once i open `ProductionCommentsActivity`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference

check your asset object and the string you passing as file name must contain in assets folder as such you provide name

Comment: Just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your DbHelper like this,

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
protected static final String DATABASE_NAME_PRODUCTION = "productionComments.db";
private Context context;

public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                     int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

       //copy database from assets folder (.sqlite) file to an empty database
        public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open("prod.db");

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = "/data/data/com.qarun.qpcbeta/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME_PRODUCTION;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
```

Comment: Basically, your context is going null which causes the crash

Comment: Thank you so much, it is now working, Jazaka Allahu Khairan Akhy :)

Comment: Never hardcode paths. This code is incorrect for hundreds of millions of Android devices (Android 4.2+ tablets, Android 5.0+ phones), as it does not support secondary accounts or Android 6.0's adoptable removable storage. While I *strongly* recommend `SQLiteAssetHelper`, at the very least, get rid of `/data/data/com.qarun.qpcbeta/databases/` and use methods [like `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)).