# How to read data from database in assets without copying

Tags: android, database, sqliteopenhelper

In database file (in assets) I need read some date without copying this databse on device.
 I didnt find answer in google for correct work.

Is it possible?

Comment: `... Is it possible?` **NO**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not do that because all the assets are compiled in a binary form and android preserve the names of all the asset's file from which it can access the file at runtime...!  [Project Resources](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/projects/index.html),  Please see the `main/assets` on the link

Android SQLiteDatabaseHelper needs some kind of InputStream...!

### Alternatives:

- You can copy the database from your assets directory to the android app directory. For refference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32499402/4360419) link...!
- You can copy the database from assets to sdcard and then access it....! Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227851/4360419) link..!
- You can use a JSON, XML or GSON format intead of SQLITE (not recommended)

Answer (score 3):

SQLite needs a local file, not merely an `InputStream`, in order to work.

Either:

- [Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) and copy the data to a local file, or
- Do not use SQLite as the storage format, but instead use something else for which you have an `InputStream`-friendly parser (e.g., JSON, using Gson)

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking about using an input stream since we can point it to an asset, but it turns out the lowest level of db call is native accepting an os file. therefore, copying to local should be the only option even it is read-only

[nativeOpen](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@5.1.1_r1@android%24database%24sqlite@SQLiteConnection@nativeOpen%28java.lang.String%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29&k=u)